# Looping through each property values of each object in an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How to loop through each object property value inside an array? I want to sanitize all values before rendering it in the front-end.

```js
sampleData = [
    { "Name": "<p>John &nbsp;</p>", "Age": 23, "Student": false },
    { "Name": "Bruno", "Age": 20, "Student": true },
    { "Name": "David &nbsp;", "Age": 30, "Student": false },
];
```

Here is the old code:

```js
this.sampleData.forEach((tableRow) => {
    let column = Object.entries(tableRow);
    column.forEach((value) => {
        let cell;
        cell = value[1];
        if ((typeof cell !== 'boolean') && (cell !== null) && (typeof cell !== 'number')) {
            cell = this.sanitizeString(cell);
        }
        console.log(cell);


    });

});
```

P.S I am using Papa parse for parsing .csv data and already have the sanitation method.

Answer (score 0):

For those who might face the same task as above, I solved it using this code:

```
this.dataPreview = this.sanitizedArray(result.data);

sanitizedArray(row) {
  Object.keys(row).forEach((key) => {
  // Sanitize each field in this scope
  return Object.keys(row[key]).forEach((column) => {
    if ( (typeof row[key][column] !== 'boolean') && (row[key][column] !== null) &(typeof row[key][column] !== 'number') ) {
    row[key][column] = this.sanitizeString(row[key][column]);
  }
  });
  // End of sanitation
});
return row;
```

}

or use my friend suggestion:

```
const updatedSampleData = sampleData.map((data) => ({ ...data, property: newValue }));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think [Sandhands](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sandhands) could be a great solution. Here's an example of how you could validate all of that data at once in a short amount of code

```js
const {sanitize} = require('sandhands')

sanitize(sampleData, [{Name: {_: String, trimmed: true}, Age: {_: Number, min: 1}, Student: Boolean}]) // throws if the sample data is not properly formatted
```

Disclosure: I wrote Sandhands, but it's free and open-source